# Can we ignore or keep playing after the Apocalypse and keep canon?

Tags: world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension

Per *Mage: The Ascension*, Consensus completely stabilizes during the Apocalypse, forever taking away the ability to cast magic on Earth. I believe it officially happened in 2006; I might be wrong about the exact year but, I am certain *World of Darkness* ended before the current day.

I don't want to switch to *Chronicles of Darkness*, as I much prefer the *Mage: The Ascension* over *Mage: The Awakening*. Is there an alternative to Apocalypse or a way to continue the game that is **still canon**? I want to keep my game canon, if possible.

Comment: It is your game, you can do whatever you want with it… What are you asking about?

Comment: Is there an alternative to apocalypses or a way to continue the game that is not non-canon? Basically i want to keep my game canon if possible.

Comment: White Wolf isn't going to send a SWAT team to kick down your doors and force you to use the Apocalypse content. If your group & storyteller don't want to play through the Apocalypse, then the Apocalypse doesn't happen for you.

Comment: Again. I want to keep things canon and i am asking if there is a source out there that allows you to continue using magic and playing despite the apocalypse happening.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Mage: The Ascension 20th Anniversary Edition.

The sourcebook explicitly tells that there is no "fixed" canon history, you can play as you want to (the Avatar Storm didn't happen etc.), but it does contain a set of events and circumstances that it considers "the base assumption". They give some background to the world until the publication of the book in 2015, so you could use those guidelines as canon history.

Answer (score 5):

### Chronicles of Darkness is a different game line.

The "new World of Darkness" games aren't sequels to the other ones, and they don't reflect a world that exists after the Time of Judgment. If you don't want to play in that setting, there's no fictional impetus to do so.

Answer (score 2):

*First of all, I don't think there is any canon way to continue your campaign with your characters as they are. But my knowledge of the Mage rules is very limited.*

This feeling comes from White Wolf's general attitude with canon being that the GM is free to ignore any part they don't like and from the fact that the New World of Darkness is not a sequel or a future version of the old one. As Jadasc says in his answer.
Those two points gives White Wolf's writer no reason to allow players to do this.

However, here's a generic answer to your question :

**Send the players back in time**

A bit of googling about Mage and time travel does not bring any hard evidence that it is impossible. [This forum](http://forum.theonyxpath.com/forum/main-category/main-forum/the-classic-world-of-darkness/mage-the-ascension/897765-time-travel-question) makes me think that true time travel is not possible with the player's power, so they would probably need external help, but you do not need to break canon.

And throwing your characters into the past can make for very interesting stories if you let them use their knowledge of the future to their advantage or indirectly interact with their past self.

I have no experience to actually GMing those kind of game. But you should probably be ready to limit the kind of things they can do with the usual paradox.